# Cumulative sum in FastReport4

Tags: fastreport

I am using FastReport4. It would be best to show you in the image sample what I need to accomplish....

First row is: Column3 = column1 - column2 
following rows need to 'build' on that initial value: if it is column1, then +, if it is column2 then -

I know I should create variables and to stora data in them, can you help me and show me by exampl how to do it.

I apologize for such a messy question.

Thank you!

[image: Third column is increased or decreased according to the value in first two columns...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your code, so I just describe the steps.

Create a variable `COLUMN3VALUE`.

Put TfrxMemoView components for your 3 columns.

Create OnBeforePrint event for Page:

```
procedure Page1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   Set('COLUMN3VALUE', 0);
end;
```

Create OnBeforePrint event for MasterData band:

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   Set('COLUMN3VALUE', Get('COLUMN3VALUE') + <reportdataset."COLUMN1"> - <reportdataset."COLUMN2">);                
end;
```

Set TfrxMemoView.Memo property for 3rd column to `[<COLUMN3VALUE>]`.

Comment: I dont have the code. As I said, I dont know from where to begin... thanks

Comment: @Volkan OK. Just follow these steps in FastReport editor.

Comment: Will try. Thank you